# Read and write bitmap to android fails

Tags: java, android, file, bitmap, android-file

I am trying to write and read a bitmap following the suggestions on other topics about this, the thing is i never get the bitmap when i try to read on the path where i saved the image:

**So i have this to write the bitmap:**

```
private String saveToInternalStorage(Bitmap bitmapImage){
        ContextWrapper cw = new ContextWrapper(getApplicationContext());
        // path to /data/data/yourapp/app_data/imageDir
        File directory = cw.getDir("imageDir", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        // Create imageDir
        File mypath=new File(directory,"captured");

        FileOutputStream fos = null;
        try {
            fos = new FileOutputStream(mypath);
            // Use the compress method on the BitMap object to write image to the OutputStream
            bitmapImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                fos.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return directory.getAbsolutePath();
    }

}
```

i pass the returned path to another activity and then i pass it as parameter to get the bitmap like this:

```
 private void loadImageFromStorage(String path)
    {

        try {
            File f=new File(path, "captured.jpg");
            Log.d("filehe",f.toString());
            b = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f));
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

i feel i am doing something wrong here, but can't figure out what, the b variavel has no value :/.

Any help?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> So i have this to write the bitmap:

The file that you save is named `captured`.

> i pass the returned path to another activity and then i pass it as parameter to get the bitmap like this

Here, you are trying to load `captured.jpg`, which is not `captured`.

You could avoid this sort of problem by having the first method return the `File` that the second method then uses.

Also:

- Use an image-loading library (e.g., Picasso, Glide) that has an in-memory cache, so you do not waste the user's time re-loading the same bitmap from disk
- Get rid of `ContextWrapper` from the first method, as you do not need it

Comment: i am using picasso, i just need to pass the bitmap to other activitie how can i use it for that purpose?

Comment: @afcosta007: "i am using picasso" -- you are not using it in that second method. "how can i use it for that purpose? " -- you used something to load the image with Picasso, such as a URL or a `Uri`. Pass that to the second activity, and have it also use Picasso. [Picasso will then use the cached bitmap where possible](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/picasso-influencing-image-caching).

Comment: so what you say, is that i can use picasso to load the bitmap from the given path on the first method?

Comment: @afcosta007: You are not loading anything in the first method. Picasso can load local images, and so you could use it in the second method.